# React.js automatically create function when named

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

**How do you automatically create a function in React.js after defining it?**

In the video below @ 3:12, he types `onClick={incrementFive}` and then a function shows up. What extension or shortcut does that?

Video: https://youtu.be/d0plTCQgsXs?t=192

Comment: Pretty sure he just cut that part out of the video (watch the cursor jump from one location to another) but that would be a pretty cool extension to build!